# JSF 1.2 - rich:calendar and f:converter causing the a4j:commandButton not to be invoked again

Tags: jsf, calendar, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am using a converter to parse the date populated from user using rich:calendar with enableManualInput set to true.

**rich:calendar** (some data has been modified for security and data privacy issues):

```jsp
<rich:calendar enableManualInput="true"
    value="#{beanAction.periodFrom}" showFooter="true"
    timeZone="#{beanAction.timeZone}"
    id="periodFrom"
    datePattern="#{beanAction.datePattern}"
    showApplyButton="true" popup="true"
    converterMessage="#{bndl.invalidDateFormat}">

        <f:converter converterId="JSFStringToDateConverter"/>

</rich:calendar>
```

And in the converter I am parsing the date using SimpleDateFormat. Though, if the parsing fails, I am executing some business logic and then throwing a ConverterException.

**Converter Method**

```java
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent,
  String inputString) throws ConverterException {
  Date date = null;
  try {
    date = simpleDateFormat.parse(inputString);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    BeanAction beanAction = (BeanAction) facesContext
      .getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext,
        "#{beanAction}", BeanAction.class);
    if (beanAction != null) {
      beanAction.setShowErrorMessagePopup(true);
    }
    throw new ConverterException();
  }
  return date;
}
```

While debugging the code, I got the action to go through the converter and if everything is OK, then to the beanAction. Else, the converter throws the exception, and the rich:message will be rendered as needed on the page.

Now **my issue** is that whatever I do on this page after the case where ConverterException is thrown, the action called through a4j:commandButton will not go through the converter or the beanAction anymore, it does nothing at all, unless I refresh the page or re-invoke the action that loads this page again.

**a4j:commandButton**

```html
<a4j:commandButton
    value="#{bndl.apply}"
    action="#{beanAction.executeAction}"
    id="applyButton" styleClass="btn"
    oncomplete="if(#{beanAction.showErrorMessagePopup}){#{rich:component('errorMessagePopup')}.show()};"
    reRender="myPageForm,errorMessagePopup,errorMessagePopupForm" />
```

---

I have really searched a lot on this particular issue with no luck, if anyone can help me, I would be more than grateful.

---

### Update

As a workaround, I have removed the thrown exception from the Converter, and handled the null value (once parsing fails) from the beanAction. Although, this solves my issue, but this is not the way I wanted to handle it. I am still concerned to know why it is not working, is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: This is just a suspicion ok, so when your converter throws an exception your view in the jsf lifecycle is marked as invalid and that is probably the reason that the a4j:button is not working, I'm not sure how to fix it though (IF i'm right, of course).

Comment: Thank you @JorgeCampos for the clarification, it sounds exactly as you mentioned.